# How to create a unique id from the first two fields in the form?

Tags: javascript, forms

I created a form with three fields **first_name, Last_name, city** and in the fourth field, I am having an Id column which is read-only. When the user fills the first three fields in the form, before submitting it should generate an id in the fourth column but here it should use the first two alphabets that are in the fields to generate an Id

For eg. First_name = Roid, Last_name = Steve, city = California then in the fourth field it should automatically generate this **id = rostca** (all the first two alphabets)

How to achieve this?

Comment: This approach won't guarantee uniqueness among the generated IDs. E.g. Robert Smith from New York and Rodney Smithers from New Jersey.

Comment: @faintsignal No sir it will because no repeated names are allowed here.

Comment: What are your efforts towards it? Did you write any code?

Comment: @JammyNemo If you're accepting duplicate IDs that's fine, but by definition they cannot be called *unique*.

Comment: Yes I did. I tried document.getElementById("textfield-id").value but its not working

Comment: @faintsignal Okay sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a JavaScript version to answer to your issue.

```js
(function () {
  populate();
})();

function populate () {
  var str = "";
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("inputs")).forEach(function (element) {
    str += element.value.substr(0, 2).toLowerCase();
  });
  document.getElementById("output").value = str;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" class="inputs" value="Roid" oninput="populate();" />
  <input type="text" class="inputs" value="Steve" oninput="populate();" />
  <input type="text" class="inputs" value="California" oninput="populate();" />
  <input id="output" type="text" readonly disabled />
</div>
```

Here is a jQuery answer to your issue.

```js
$(function () {
  populate();
  
  $(".inputs").on("input", function() {
    populate();
  });
});

function populate () {
  var str = "";
  $(".inputs").each(function () {
    str += $(this).val().substr(0, 2).toLowerCase();
  });
  $("#output").val(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="inputs" value="Roid" />
  <input type="text" class="inputs" value="Steve" />
  <input type="text" class="inputs" value="California" />
  <input id="output" type="text" readonly disabled />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank a lot sir..This is enough.thanks for your time

Comment: If in this form i am using radio button means, whether this concept  will work?

Comment: I just tried that but for radio button this is not working

Comment: I do not know how you would do this with radio buttons. Maybe write a new question? So this question can stay on topic and in the next question you write you can give a better example.

Comment: Okay Sir..i will do it

Answer (score 1):

Check below code,

```js
 function TextChanged(){
        var first_name =  document.getElementById("first_name").value;
        var Last_name =  document.getElementById("Last_name").value;
        var city =  document.getElementById("city").value; 
      
        document.getElementById("id").value =  first_name.substring(0, 2) +Last_name.substring(0, 2) +city.substring(0, 2);  
    }
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="first_name" onblur="TextChanged()">
    <input type="text" id="Last_name" onblur="TextChanged()">
    <input type="text" id="city" onblur="TextChanged()">
    <input type="text" id="id" readonly>
```

Check here jsbin demo, https://jsbin.com/qegazab/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I learned my Mistake now.  Its Perfect

Comment: Hi, do you know about [the snippet editor](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: No sir...i don't know

Comment: @msanford added,

Comment: @programtreasures Please tell me how to use this concept in radio button field. Incase i want to add radio button.